# Why does {{ isNan(x) }} not work in angularJS?

Tags: angularjs

Note the title of this question has changed to one that's more focused to the exact problem. See the comment stream to follow how it came about that I realized the problem is that AngularJS does not seem to handle {{ isNaN() }}

I have the following in my HTML:

```
xx {{ option.selectedSubject }} yy {{ (option.selectedSubject == null) }} zz
```

and I also tried:

```
xx {{ option.selectedSubject }} yy {{ option.selectedSubject == null }} z
```

and:

```
xx {{ option.selectedSubject }} yy {{ option.selectedSubject === null }} zz
```

Can someone help explain to me why I get the following for each of the above when I view my page:

```
xx null yy false zz
```

**Update 1** I tried the following:

```
aa {{ option.selectedSubject === "null" }} bb {{ option.selectedSubject == "null" }} cc
```

and it gives this:

```
aa false bb false cc
```

**Update 2** I am not sure if this helps but here's what populates the values of option.selectedSubject. In this case there's nothing in local storage:

```
$scope.option.selectedSubject = parseInt(localStorage.get('selectedSubject'));
```

When I check the value of $scope.option.selectedSubject it is **NaN**

Comment: What are you hoping to see?

Comment: Any chance you're setting `option.selectedSubject` to "null" instead of `null`?  Check out: http://jsfiddle.net/y3xzB/1/

Comment: you might be doing === instead of == with "null" instead of `null` http://jsfiddle.net/y3xzB/1/

Comment: I added another test for "null" and the output is shown in the question now.

Comment: sry http://jsfiddle.net/y3xzB/2/

Comment: Could there be extra characters in `option.selectedSubject`? For instance "null "(note the extra space). That can produce what you're seeing:  http://jsfiddle.net/y3xzB/3/

Comment: See my comment to the answer by Michael. Here it shows the output when I did {{ option }}  It just shows :null

Comment: Can you check the length of your string.  For instance add  `Length: {{option.selectedSubject.length}}` to your html.  If it's more than 4 then we know something else is hidden in there.

Comment: I tried Length: {{option.selectedSubject.length}} xxx and it gave me "Length: xxx"

Comment: Can you reproduce it in a plnker or a fiddle? Because I can't... http://plnkr.co/edit/qXinJxY5YeYYNY4YwI1P?p=preview

Comment: When you get this result:  "xx null yy false zz"  are you getting the string value "null" or literally the character null?  (such that it appears like this: "xx yy false zz")

Comment: This is what appears: "xx null yy false zz"

Comment: try {{ isNaN(option.selectedSubject) }}

Comment: NaN- that makes sense now.  What you're seeing is expected behavior for NaN- you just need to use a NaN test instead of testing for null and you'll be set

Comment: BBB {{ isNaN(option.selectedSubject) }} BBB

gives:


BBB BBB

Comment: Finally had some success. I moved the isNaN outside of the {{ }} and into a function. I then called the function and passed the parameter option.selectedSubject. Inside that function I checked and it was being passed a NaN. isNotNumber: function (num) {
            var a = isNaN(num);  the value of a is true.  So it seems that I must use an external function to check the value.

Comment: Yes this is weird. On my side it worked when I added $scope.isNaN = isNaN; in the controller. This is similar to what you did.

Comment: Samantha and @Galdo perhaps it's browser-dependent. `$scope.isNaN = function(n) { return isNaN(n); };` should work.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The problem here is not isNaN. The problem is that you are calling a function on the $scope variable that does not exist.

Every interpolated piece of text ( '{{ text }}' ), is associated to a $scope variable and evaluated against that $scope variable.

To make things easy for you, $scope.property can be created on the fly if it doesn't exist. Anytime you use ngModel='someProperty' or {{ aPropertyName }}, then the corressponding $scope.someProperty or $scope.aPropertyName is created for you automatically if it didn't already exist. This shortcut only works with primitives, however.

Function calls are always evaluated against $scope, and never created. This is why you have to say $scope.isNaN = isNaN, as you found in your earlier comment.

Try it with any function. isArray, isNumber, etc. It won't work unless you have put a $scope.functionName = functionName in a controller somewhere.

Edit: Also, if you REALLY want to do the isNaN test right in the interpolation, you can take advantage of javascript's type system and use

```
{{ property != property }}
```

But this is bad form...

http://plnkr.co/edit/wfLqzk8QxScsJPF5qY12?p=preview

Answer (score 3):

**Edit :** The original question was ***Can I have a test inside {{ }} in angularJS?***, and `$scope.option.selectedSubject` was meant to be `null` and not `NaN`. The author should have open another question instead of changing it to a complete different one.

---

*Answer to the original question :*

You can put an expression inside your binding, hence you can test {{ option.selectedSubject == null }}. Check your scope if the result of the evaluation is not what you are expecting.

Comment: I am not sure what more to check. Here's what's in option: {"selectedSubject":null,"..... etc.