# Using NaN with condition

Tags: angularjs

I have one division in my modal ,I only required to show the div when the value of a variable `$scope.ornamentweightinbank` is not equal to `NaN`.

```
<div class="rows container-fluid" ng-if="ornamentweightinbank!==NaN">
```

Is this the conventional way to deal with `NaN`

Comment: Try adding `$scope.NaN = NaN;` - I think it will work

Comment: @AlonEitan In my controller?

Comment: are you checking `ornamentweightinbank` in not a number validation or just string `NaN`

Comment: @AjithVManali Yup. Because I don't think Angular know that you're comparing it to JS's NaN, but to an undefined property in the scope

Answer (score 2):

You can access JavaScript's native [`isNaN`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/isNaN) function by creating a similar function on `this` within your controller, you can then access it in your [`ngIf`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngIf) directive like so:

```js
(function() {

  'use strict';

  angular.module('app', []);

})();

(function() {

  'use strict';

  angular.module('app').controller('MainController', MainController);

  MainController.$inject = ['$scope', '$timeout'];

  function MainController($scope, $timeout) {

    // make isNaN available in your view via controller as syntax
    this.isNaN = function(value) {

      return isNaN(value);

    }

    // set ornamentweightinbank to a number
    $scope.ornamentweightinbank = 10;

    // for demonstrative purposes set ornamentweightinbank to NaN after 5 seconds
    $timeout(function() {

      $scope.ornamentweightinbank = 10 * "test";

    }, 5000);

  }

})()
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.1/angular.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="MainController as MainCtrl">

  <div class="rows container-fluid" ng-if="!MainCtrl.isNaN(ornamentweightinbank)">
    This will show if ornamentweightinbank is not equal to NaN
  </div>

  <div class="rows container-fluid" ng-if="MainCtrl.isNaN(ornamentweightinbank)">
    This will show if ornamentweightinbank is equal to NaN
  </div>

</div>
```

Please see [this stackoverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20728115/3453034) why you cannot directly use `isNaN` in your expression.

Answer (score 0):

There is one way where in you can make the isNaN function available in html i.e. by assigning it in scope/this of the current controller.

```
this.isNaN = function(value){ //or $scope.isNaN = function(value){
return isNaN(value);
}
```

which when used in HTML,

```
<span ng-class="{'color-red':!isNaN(value)}" ng-bind="value"></span>
```

I suppose for any kind of Javascript Native functions which I might require inside HTML, I prefer making a copy of windows object in rootScope.

```
$rootScope.windowInstance = window;
```

this will allow us to use any kind of window functions in html,

```
<span 
ng-class="{'color-red' : !windowInstance['isNaN'](value) && windowInstance['parseFloat'](value) < 0}" 
ng-bind="value">
</span>
<!-- Will color the value red when the value is Number and negative -->
```